# Get the value from shell script to java

Tags: java, shell

I have a shell script like this.

```
 #!/bin/sh

s=$1
pro=`ps -ef | grep $s | grep -v grep | grep -v test3.sh`
pro1=`ps -ef | grep $s | grep -v grep | grep -v test3.sh | wc -l`

echo $pro
echo $pro1

if [ $pro1 -eq 0 ]
    then
            echo "Service $s is DOWN..."
            echo "Service $s is DOWN..." >> processlogs.txt
            echo "Starting Service $s..."
            echo "Starting Service $s..." >> processlogs.txt
            java -jar clientApplication.jar "$s" &
            exit 0

    else
            echo "Service $s is Running..."
            echo "Service $s is Running..." >> processlogs.txt

   fi
```

Now I want the value of $s to java program. What should I do for this. Thanks.

Comment: I just want ti insert the log in database from java application.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some more explanation. Are you simply trying to write the equivalent of this program in Java? Or are you wanting to specifically run this script and capture the output in Java? More info please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This...

```
Process p = Runtime.exec("myExeOrShellScript");
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine())!=null) {
  // got the output in 'line' do something with it
}
r.close();
```

whatever you pump out in your shell script with `echo` will end up in the java program.

Answer (score 1):

Check args:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```